why is passing a copy of array faster then reference array?
I was trying to compare the efficiency of the if statement compared to initialization of a loop in two basic code snippets where one snippet first compares the values first using if statement and then uses a while loop and the other snippet directly uses while loop to check statement. Using the code :
import time

def snippet1(nums):
    nums.sort()
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] <= nums[i-1]:
            while nums[i] <= nums[i-1]:
                nums[i] += 1
                c += 1
    return c

def snippet2(nums):
    nums.sort()
    c = 0
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        while nums[i] <= nums[i-1]:
            nums[i] += 1
            c += 1
    return c

# Sample list of numbers
nums = [5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2, 5]

# Measure time for snippet1
start_time = time.time()
snippet1(nums)
end_time = time.time()
print("Time for snippet1:", end_time - start_time)

# Measure time for snippet2
start_time = time.time()
snippet2(nums)
end_time = time.time()
print("Time for snippet2:", end_time - start_time)

Though the results were as estimated, the result became weird when I changed "nums[:]" to "nums" in the driver code. The only effect was on the result time of snippet2 where when using nums[:] the avg time was 1.5 seconds and with nums it became 5 seconds whereas time of snippet1 remained the same in both cases with avg of 2s.
It doesn't makes sense to me how passing a array copy or passing a array reference affects only the if statement?
Result with nums[:]:
Time for snippet1: 1.52587890625e-05
Time for snippet2: 1.430511474609375e-05

=== Code Execution Successful ===

Result with nums:
Time for snippet1: 2.0265579223632812e-05
Time for snippet2: 5.245208740234375e-06

=== Code Execution Successful ===


snippet2 is getting an already sorted list as its argument, which is faster to sort than the original unsorted list. That may be the only difference.

For additional context, You might check out Which sort algorithm works best on mostly sorted data?

When timing such short-lived operations, better to use timeit to run your functions multiple times to get a better view of the real durations

Use a profiler to see where the time is being spent. That will likely confirm @chepner's suspicion that it's in the sort, not passing the array.
